# Get report from OWASP Zap session

Tags: cypress, zap

I'm trying to get OWASP ZAP to run while I run my cypress tests. I think have it working but can't get a human readable report out. I'm running the daemon

```
cross-env-shell java -jar ./zap/zap-D-2022-05-16.jar -daemon -port 8080 -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config api.disablekey=true -newsession $INIT_CWD/zap-results/session
```

then I run my cypress test proxied through the port the daemon is running on. I can see the zap-results folder populated, but am not sure how to get an html or similar report from here.
[image: zap-results]

I see references to the `-last_scan_report` option but that seems depreciated in the build I have. I also don't seem to be able import the session GUI either.

Do I need to change something in my daemon config and/or what cli command can run to export a report?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, dont run ZAP via the jar - its not designed to be run that way. Use the zap.sh or zap.bat command as appropriate.
The recommended ways to automate ZAP are given on https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/

If you are OK using Docker then the packaged scans are a good option, otherwise I'd recommend the Automation Framework.

Note that the ZAP User Group is the best way to get help on using ZAP: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users